# Why was my question about ITIL closed?

Tags: discussion, support, specific-question, closed-questions

Regarding: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5666914/is-a-service-request-considered-an-incident
I'm a new user on Stack Overflow and I don't understand the logic of closing of this post. I've read the FAQ and effectively the question is probably off-topic, but I have also seen many questions with similar topics that are still open:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4225542/itil-v3-compliant-trouble-ticketing-systems
- [Who is responsible for software licensing in ITIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2849210/who-is-responsible-for-software-licensing-in-itil)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580192/release-change-management-best-aproach
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/880241/difference-between-a-bug-and-an-incident

Reading these other questions and their many responses, while noting their votes for the clarity and usefulness, I thought my question was acceptable.

Other related questions:

- [Does ITIL fit into an Agile world?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3733638/does-itil-fit-into-an-agile-world)
- [Which are the best IT methodology standards for a web development company?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1752911/which-are-the-best-it-methodology-standards-for-a-web-development-company)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1522719/what-would-be-the-most-useful-certification-for-a-developer-itil
- [What is the impact of ITIL or CMMI on the development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/618990/what-is-the-impact-of-itil-or-cmmi-on-the-development)
- [Looking for pragmatic CMDB solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208292/looking-for-pragmatic-cmdb-solution)
- [What is the best way to handle change management?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184652/what-is-the-best-way-to-handle-change-management)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105738/project-framework-management-certifications

Comment: May be all questions you've mentioned in this post are off-topic, on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Voted to close all four questions.

Comment: They are all closed or migrated to programmers now.

Comment: Voted to close as off topic all seven new questions.

Comment: Did the SE engine just get tired of managing links-to-titles, you think?

Comment: "Why is my question closed here are other examples of off-topic questions that have slipped through, or are from the first year of SO, and haven't been closed yet"

Comment: Sure, all is off-topic. It could create a stack-offtopic to accommodate the novices's questions. But on FAQ I read "This is not a random discussion board, this is a place for improving our community and websites!". Improving is also indicate what are the off-topic questions

Comment: @ema Thanks for identifying so many off topic questions for us!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I've read the FAQ and effectively the question probably is off-topic...

Good to see that someone is actually reading and understanding the FAQ if his question is closed. `:)`

> ...but I have also seen many similar topic question.

These are relicts and/or slipped through the system. Watch them go down. `8-)`